# ViewPager onClickListener don't work - shuts app down with an error

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer, onclicklistener

I have this problem with ViewPager nad onClickListener. I want to have gallery of images (that one works perfectly). The problem comes when I want it to be clickable so it will play a sound depending on image actually viewed. That's the main thing. The other is to add floating buttons, but it's the secondary case.

Working code:

```
int file = sounds[position];
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, file);

    imggun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            mp.start();
```

//                mediaPlayer.start();

```
        }
    });
```

edit:
if I get rid of compile errors with code like this:

```
imggun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int file = R.raw.beerburp;
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), file);
            mp.start();

        }
    });
```

I get that from LogCat:

```
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     atandroid.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:668)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at com.example.package_name.ViewPagerAdapter$1.onClick(ViewPagerAdapter.java:81)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-10 12:53:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1380):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use Youractivity.this instead of getApplicationContext().

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya if I use MainActivity.this then this compile error get marked:
"No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"
and when I use ViewPagerAdapter.this then 'create' from this line gets compile error like this:
"The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (ViewPagerAdapter, int)"

Comment: You have to chage here MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), file);

Comment: This what I've done before. Should I share more of the code? Maybe there's something missing in the other areas?

Answer (score 0):

what is the error message you get when running this or is this more of a logical error where you click an item and it doesnt play a sound but no syntax compile errors?

Comment: 01-09 20:35:35.391: E/AndroidRuntime(12384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 20:35:35.391: E/AndroidRuntime(12384): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 20:35:35.391: E/AndroidRuntime(12384):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:668)
01-09 20:35:35.391: E/AndroidRuntime(12384):  at com.example.<myproject>.ViewPagerAdapter$1.onClick(ViewPagerAdapter.java:81)

Comment: If I somewhat get rid of compile errors then after click app force closes.

Comment: can you verify that sounds is not null at this line of code:
   int file =  sounds[position];

Comment: I have updated my question with both compile errors and errors-free (with LogCat file) @reidisaki

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I use this code in onClick:

```
int file = sounds[position];
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), file);
mp.start();
```

I get NullPointerException on second line (MediaPlayer mp = ...). I think it may be the way to go.